# Design tag order change in android studio while Rearrange/Reformat(command+ALT+L) the code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Before updating my android studio my code looked like this with Rearrange/Reformat(command+ALT+L) the code

Many of the users reported this issue here

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=Ctrl%2BAlt%2BL

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139769915

> **Short cut for Reformat the code**
>
> Windows: Ctrl + Alt + L
>
> Linux: Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L
>
> macOS: Option + Command + L

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".view.activity.UserFollowingActivity">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.socket.chat.viewmodel.ConversionListVM" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But after update the android studio my code order change while Rearrange/Reformat(command+ALT+L) the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".view.activity.UserFollowingActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.socket.chat.viewmodel.ConversionListVM" />
    </data>
</layout>
```

> It was changed in every design XML file and AndroidManifest.xml file.

So how can do it that with the old way?

Comment: I had the exact same issue as you @Mayur. I fixed by going to *Preferences > Editor > Code Style > XML > Tab: Arrangement > Additional settings:* **Force rearrange: Never**.

Comment: This has been answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591080/android-studio-3-5-refactor-issue

Answer (score 6):

Just change this setting in preference > code style > XML and you are good to go.
hope it helps.
It is a bug in the latest 3.5 update.

[Tap here to see setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S5Xq.png)

Comment: Its is same as you have mention