# Android studio 3.5 refactor issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I've just updated to Android Studio 3.5 and now when I try to refactor the file `AndroidManifest.xml`, all my app permissions are moved to the bottom of the file.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there any solution for this?

Before refactor:

[image]

After refactor:

[image]

It is applicable to my all project files.

#### Why it matters:

[image]

Comment: why is this a problem that requires a solution?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: If nothing else, it introduces unexpected noise in version control. I can't rule out real problems in old Android devices, as `<uses-permission>` used to need to appear before `<application>`, though it is possible that was really an old tooling problem that we would not see nowadays.

Comment: FWIW, [I wrote up more about the problem](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/21/android-studio-3p5-xml-reformatting-problems.html), including filing [a dedicated issue for the 3.4 -> 3.5 upgrade problem](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139793887) that triggers this effect.

Comment: @TimCastelijns in a xml layout, it changes the order of you components (ex : my ImageView came before my TextView, and that's not what I want !)

Comment: They just undid all of their efforts towards stability with 3.5 with this. Probably the worst AS bug ever since it can silently break your app at run time :/

Comment: ridiculous bug!

Answer (score 269, accepted):

You just need to set xml layout for Android applications from the settings.

Follow this steps:

**1.** Go to **Android Studio** > **Preferences**. For Windows, go to **File** > **Settings**.

[image]

**2.** Search for **xml** in search bar.

[image]

**3.** Under **code style** section, select **xml** tab.

[image]

**4.** In the top right corner, click on **set from...** and under **predefined style**, select **Android**

[image]

**5.** Click on Apply and try to refactor.

Comment: After this you may need to restart Android Studio.

Comment: This got me most the way there but I think the issue is the lack of "attribute" property tag's in the arrangement tab. See the screenshot in my own answer for details.

Comment: From what I can tell the reason this suggestion works is because it inserts these "attribute" type tags, though it does so at the cost of resetting any other customisations you may have set so you'll have to re-implement those again after, but it work's :).

Comment: I am afraid that this solution is not working in my case.

Comment: On Android Studio 4.0.1, this bug still exists. It changes the order of my components in xml layout when reformatting. So ridiculous!

Answer (score 17):

**Reset the appropriate Android code style as follows.**

> For **Windows** Only

**Step1:** Click on the **file** menu.

**Step2:** Navigate to **Setting**.

**Step3:** Find **Editor** in the Left Panel**.

**Step4:** Find **Code Style** in the Sub Menu of Editor.

**Step5:** Click on **XML** in the Sub Menu of Code Style.

**Step6:** Click on **Set from** in Top right corner of Right panel.

**Step7:** Select **Predefined Style**.

**Step8:** Select **Android**.

**Step9:** Click **OK**.

> For **macOS** Only

**Step1:** Click on the **Android Studio** menu.

**Step2:** Navigate to **Preferences**.

**Step3:** Find **Editor** in the Left Panel**.

**Step4:** Find **Code Style** in the Sub Menu of Editor.

**Step5:** Click on **XML** in the Sub Menu of Code Style.

**Step6:** Click on **Set from** in Top right corner of Right panel.

**Step7:** Select **Predefined Style**.

**Step8:** Select **Android**.

**Step9:** Click **OK**.

Answer (score 10):

It seems the default scheme leaves out the "attribute" property in the arrangement rules. Adding them back in works like a charm for me.

The correction can be made in: **Preferences > Editor > Code Style > XML**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just adding more details .

This is a known issue with android studio from Android Studio 3.5 Canary 8 . It should get fixed in next version as this turned out to affect large number of developers .

You can see status of the bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129457736)

Also the solution is

> **Broken XML code style**
>
> When editing XML code, the IDE might apply an incorrect code style when you select Code > Reformat Code from the menu bar. To fix this issue, reset the appropriate Android code style as follows:
>
> 1. Open the Settings window by clicking File > Settings (on macOS, Android Studio > Preferences).
> 2. In the left panel, click Editor > Code Style > XML.
> 3. Near the top-right corner of the right panel, select Set from > Predefined Style > Android
> 4. Click OK.

Which is found here -> [Known issues with Android Studio and Android Gradle Plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#xml-code-style)

**Edit:**  This is now fixed in Android studio version [3.5.2](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/11/android-studio-352-available.html)

Answer (score 3):

- ctrl + alt + s
- Search XML

I wanted to do the same steps as the first answer, but I just needed to change the default scheme to project.

I hope that you also solve it this way . Sorry for my English !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom code style defined, you have to specify a type for each rule: tag or attribute.

It seems like after the update, if you do not specify a type, the rules will be applied to both. Not sure if it is a bug, but that's how i fixed.

[This does not work on 3.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzZZj.png)

[After adding the attribute type to each rule, it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DgSA.png)

Answer (score 1):

> **Please follow these steps for Windows version of "Android Studio 3.5"**

**1: Click on the File in the Menu.**

**2: Go to Settings.**

**[image].**

**3: Click on Editor.**

**4: Click on Code Style**

**5: Click on XML.**

[image]

**6: Click on "Set from..." in top-right corner.**

**7: Select Predefined Style.**

**8: Select Android.**

[image]

**9: Click OK.**

Answer (score 1):

### 3.5.0 known issue

When editing XML code, the IDE might apply an incorrect code style when you select **Code > Reformat Code** from the menu bar. To fix this issue, reset the appropriate Android code style as follows:

- Open the Settings window by clicking **File > Settings** (on macOS,
  **Android Studio > Preferences**).
- In the left panel, click **Editor > Code Style > XML**.
- Near the top-right corner of the right panel, select **Set from >
  Predefined Style > Android**.
- Click **OK**.

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone searching this for Android Studio 4+ :**

```
File -> Setting -> Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Arrangement ->
```

- Set Force rearrange to "Never"
- Set from to "Android"