# Navigation Drawer items not showing anything

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have updated the Android Studio to version 3.5 from August 9 2019. I have tried to get familiar with new idea for navigation drawer using Navigation Component. I created the new project and chose the Navigation Drawer Activity at start. After that, I have tried to run the app to see if everything works fine but the drawer menu doesn't work. The drawer gets open but when I click on any available items it just close the drawer not opening proper fragment. I have also tried to set different fragment as a Start Destination and it works fine, the correct fragment gets open at start correctly however the drawer menu still doesn't work.

What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Code comes straight from the fresh new Navigation Drawer Activity:

activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

mobile_navigation:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.tools.ToolsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_tools"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tools" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.share.ShareFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_share"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_share" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:name="com.broadenup.test.ui.send.SendFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_send"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: There's an issue in the 3.5 upgrade that might be improperly formatting the XML in your project. Please post the `activity_main` layout.

Comment: Thx @MikeM. for reply, I have updated the question with code.

Comment: The drawer in a `<DrawerLayout>` must be listed last in order for it to receive touch events properly. Move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<include>` in `activity_main`.

Comment: If you did not modify that file yourself initially, then it's likely due to an issue in the 3.5 upgrade for Android Studio that causes XML to be rearranged incorrectly. If that's your case, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57591080) to see how to fix that.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution fixed the problem. Thanks so much @MikeM. I was getting annoyed why even new project doesn't work. I will take a look at the refactor issue. Thx :)