# How to fix Android studio 3.5 navigation activity template onNavigationItemSelected not working

Tags: android

I created a new navigation drawer activity from Android Studio 3.5 templates, but menu items are not clickable even though I'm listening for `NavigationItemSelected`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I click an item from the drawer, the drawer just closes instead of displaying the Toast in defined in the `onNavigationItemSelected` method.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the layout XML that has the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: This is still a problem in Android Studio 4.0.1 stable version...(are you listening, Google?)...the accepted answer to the questions fixes this.

Comment: Would be nice if anyone using 4.1 (currently not stable version) or 4.2 betas could comment if it has been fixed in those versions?

Comment: So - still a problem in Android Studio 4.1 stable version that was just released.....should have been fixed by Google. The accepted solution here is still needed.

Comment: So finally seems to be fixed in Android Studio 4.1.2, where the order in the xml file is correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

this problem is caused by the ordering issue of xml file from main content

the default order:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

change to following order:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Comment: For those wondering why this is the correct answer, it is to do with Z order, the NavigationView must be on top of the other controls to receive input. Controls in the  XML layout file are ordered bottom -> top, therefore to be the top most control, it must be declared last.

Comment: @BitByteDog Thanks a lot for your explanation about the Z order of XML layout. I'm also confused about why changing order can make such effect.

Comment: The Android documentation for [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout) is specific, the content view must be placed first, the NavigationView is second. The ordering matters. There are several other container views where ordering matters, for example [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). Just check the documentation for each control to see if the order of views is significant .

Comment: Good job, Google.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)`, you're saying that you want `NavController` to handle click events from your NavigationView, navigating to the related screen as per [the NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer). This, by necessity, calls `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` internally, overriding the `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` you call earlier in `onCreate()`. If you've hooked up your `NavigationView` to fragments in your app (as the template does out of the box), then there is no need to call `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` yourself.

Of course, you should ensure that your layout has not changed from what the Navigation Drawer Activity gives you by default - there is a [known issue with Android Studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591080/android-studio-3-5-refactor-issue) that can lead to the order of views being changed which would break cases like `DrawerLayout` (where the order of children matters greatly)

Comment: So, it should still be calling `onNavigationItemSelected()`, right? I would assume they've added the `setNavigationItemSelectedListener()` call in an effort to debug.

Comment: @MikeM. - NavigationView only allows one listener set at a time - since NavigationUI is set last, its internal listener is called.

Comment: Oop, never mind. I confused that with something else (that's not there; I'm not familiar with Navigation yet). My bad. Anyway, I'll still bet it's a debug attempt after it didn't work out of the box.

Comment: Hi all guys, I'm having the same problem with same Android Studio version: when i click on any entry of the drawer, it just closes and doesn't navigate to the new fragment. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @MatteoBelfiori If yours is the same issue I've been seeing, [this issue in the 3.5 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57591080) is causing XML to be improperly reordered, and it's moving the `<NavigationView>` to above (and therefore, behind) the main content in the `<DrawerLayout>`. You'll need to move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<include>` (or whatever else you might have for the main content). Then follow the steps in the accepted answer on that linked post, so it doesn't happen again when reformatting/refactoring later.

Comment: @MikeM.Oh man, thank you so much. Now it works, just by moving the NavigationView as you said. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Ian, if this ends up being the OP's original issue here, as I suspect, would you please amend your answer to address that, so I can use this as a dupe target in the future? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeM. - I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Oh yes finally, it works thanks a lot guys. It was an issue with the reordering of the views like you said.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, consider accepting the answer to remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

Inside XML the tag `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>` in the activity
Rearrangement  first and `<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>`
Second . 
Inside java onCreate example :

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                             @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"home",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"nav_gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"nav_slideshow",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_tools) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"nav_tools",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_share) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"nav_share",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_send) {
                    Toast.makeText(Permissions_Display.this,"nav_send",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**

> For Menu Items Clickable

**
NavController offers an OnDestinationChangedListener interface that is called when the NavController's current destination or its arguments change. A new listener can be registered via the addOnDestinationChangedListener() method. Note that when calling addOnDestinationChangedListener(), if the current destination exists, it is immediately sent to your listener.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
           @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
       if(destination.getId() == R.id.gallery) {
           //statements
       } else {
       //statements
}
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                     @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
        if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_cart) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"nav_cart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_orders) {
            Intent in =new Intent(HomeActivity.this, OrdersActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"nav_gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_categories) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"nav_categories",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_settings) {
            Intent in =new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"nav_settings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } if(destination.getId() == R.id.nav_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"nav_logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```