# Android Studio: unexpected Reformat Code in XML layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.5

I am using Android Studio 3.5 now and after last update, I observed unexpected auto-formatting of XML layout.

In my layout I have:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...
<TextView ...
<ImageView ...
<TextView ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After reformat code  `Code -> Reformat Code`
my layout changes in an unespected and unwanted form :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...
<ImageView ...
<TextView ...
<TextView ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Question**

- Is this a feature in new AS? then how can I revert it back?
- Did I change some setting? What setting should I modify to revert back?

Comment: Also look into this https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/21/android-studio-3p5-xml-reformatting-problems.html

Comment: I found the right solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591080/android-studio-3-5-refactor-issue