# onNavigationItemSelected() problems

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

when  click  on  any  menu item, there  is  no response, they  suppose  to  navigate  to  Destination  Fragment

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        item.setChecked(true);

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.mealFragment:
                navController.navigate(R.id.mealFragment);
                break;

            case R.id.drinksFragment:
                navController.navigate(R.id.drinksFragment);
                break;

            case R.id.dessertFragment:
                navController.navigate(R.id.dessertFragment);
                break;

        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }






// setting up on time Navigation 

private void setUpNavigation() {
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawer);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

after  call  setUpNavigation() .
App keeps sticking  on mealFragment()  as its start Destination on navigation  graph

Comment: If `bringToFront()` fixed your issue, then the `<View>`s inside your `<DrawerLayout>` in the layout XML are in the wrong order. The drawer `<NavigationView>` must be listed last in order to end up on top, and receive touch events properly. If you did not move the `<View>`s like that yourself, then it's possibly due to an issue in the 3.5 upgrade for Android Studio that causes XML to be rearranged improperly. If that's your case, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57591080) to see how to fix it.

Comment: Also, setting your own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` like that is overriding the `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` call, essentially defeating the purpose of the Navigation framework there, which should be handling the `Fragment` navigation for you automatically. If you did that in an attempt to fix the drawer issue, you can remove that after fixing your layout, and the IDE issue.

Comment: yes, the problem  came  after  3.5  android  studio update, overriding  the  framework  method  just  to  check  where  the  error  and  why  navigation isn't  work

Comment: Yeah, it's a common issue. You should just have to rearrange your layout XML, and then you can go back to using the Navigation framework.

Answer (score 1):

I was programmatically adding `HeaderView` to `NavigationView` Hence I already had `NavigationView`

I called `navigationView.bringToFront();`

Here is code snippet for context :

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.bringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set listner for navigationView as:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

befor implementing the onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 as:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with a *Log.d()* call if the *onNavigationItemSelected* event is fired or not. If not, check your the layout file for the clickable attribute:

```
<DrawerLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```